# How to make virtual machines see each other and host

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, kvm

We have Virtual Machines operating within the KVM environment.  We setup one as a dev server running apache etc and the other as a Windows development environment.

The two environments are setup and running fine.  However, they cannot ping (see) each other.  I am wondering if there is a clear solution to this.

This is what is happening.

From Host:
      Cannot ping either of 2 VM's (one linux, one windows)

From Either of the VM's:
      Cannot ping host
      Cannot ping each other

From other network machines (for instance my laptop from within my company network)
      Successfully ping host at 192.168.0.64
      Successfully ping VM1 (Linux) 192.168.0.43
      Successfully ping VM2 (Windows) 192.168.0.84

What sayeth the group ?

Jay Lepore
CompuMatter